# Having trouble creating a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to find the mean price for the rear wheel drive car prices in the R pre-specified data frame Cars93. Here is what I tried... I'm getting an unexpected for error.

```
library(MASS) # has Cars93 data

rearcar <- c()
for(train in 1:nrow(Cars93)){
   if(Cars93$DriveTrain[train] == Rear){
   rearcar <- c(rearcar, train)
   }
}

rearcarprice <- c()
for (train in rearcar){
    rearcarprice <- c(rearcarprice, Cars93[train,6])
}

mean(rearcarprice)
```

Comment: First of all, you have mismatched curly braces. Second of all, you should post an example data set of `Cars93`.

Comment: When asking a question where you're getting an error, make a habit of including the error text.

Comment: You forgot the quotes: `if(Cars93$DriveTrain[train] == "Rear")`

Comment: Don't use a loop! I tend to use `dplyr` for these questions, but my preferred base solution is: `with(Cars93, tapply(Price, DriveTrain, mean))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a for loop at all for this.

This gives the subset of the data with "Rear" drivetrain:

```
Cars93[Cars93$DriveTrain == "Rear", ]
```

This is the "Price" column for that data subset:

```
Cars93[Cars93$DriveTrain == "Rear", "Price"]
```

Thus, this is the average price for that subset:

```
mean(Cars93[Cars93$DriveTrain == "Rear", "Price"])
# 28.95
```

All you need is that last line of code.

Comment: thank you, realized this right after I posted the question

Answer (score 1):

Try correcting your mismatched curly braces as a starting point. And also make sure to put `Rear` in quotes.

```
library(MASS)
rearcar<-c()
for(train in 1:nrow(Cars93))
{
  if(Cars93$DriveTrain[train] == 'Rear'){
    rearcar <- c(rearcar, train)
  }
}
rearcarprice <- c()
for (train in rearcar) {
  rearcarprice <- c(rearcarprice, Cars93[train,6])
}
mean(rearcarprice)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a backwards set bracket on the first for loop.

Current

```
for(train in 1:nrow(Cars93))
    }
    if(Cars93$DriveTrain[train] == Rear){
    rearcar <- c(rearcar, train)
    }}
```

Try:

```
for(train in 1:nrow(Cars93))
{
if(Cars93$DriveTrain[train] == Rear){
rearcar <- c(rearcar, train)
}}
```